# excel vba data not saved properly from listboxes

Tags: excel, vba

I have been pulling my hair out for a few days now even after researching so I am just giving up and asking for help.

I have two userforms. First I select an item from a listbox on the Main form and then press a button on the main form. The sub form opens after the button is pressed.

Then there are some comboboxes and listboxes on the subform. When I click the save button on the subform the data from the boxes(listbox and comboboxes) is saved on a separate sheet.

Everything seems to work OK until I re-select the item on the main form and then try to save the changes on the subform. For some reason the worksheet that has the subform data just got rewritten by blanks (seems randomly too) ( the controls are named as control1, control2,...control47 for looping when saving the data.

I have a `loadform` sub to read the data back to the `listbox`. When I debug (debug.frm.controls("control" & i),  it seems not to be loading the `listbox` (comboboxes seem to be OK) however somehow it still shows properly in the `listbox`.  Only when I try to save the changes, it blanks out some of the entries instead of saving the changes.

`loading subform`:

```
For x = 1 To 47
    answer = survey.Cells(findr, x + 9).Value
    If answer = "" Then
        frmSurvey.Controls("reg" & x).Value = ""
    Else
        m = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(answer, list.Range("table_s" & x))
        frmSurvey.Controls("reg" & x).ListIndex = m - 1
        frmSurvey.Controls("reg" & x).Selected(m - 1) = True
        frmSurvey.Controls("reg" & x).Value = answer
    End If
```

`saving`:

```
For i = 1 To 47
 For m = 0 To frmSurvey.Controls("reg" & i).ListCount - 1
      If frmSurvey.Controls("reg" & i).Selected(m) = True Then
           ws.Cells(findr, i + 9) = frmSurvey.Controls("reg" & i).Value
      End If
 Next m
```

Next i

I think the problem is in the loading. I thought it's because even the value is assigned, it is not selected so the listbox is not loaded properly. But even when I added `.select(i)=true`, it still doesn't work.

Or maybe it's something else? Thanks very much if someone can offer help!

Comment: have you thought about setting a break point at the start of the code and stepping through it until things start to go south?

Comment: Yes I did. When I debug the frmsurvey.controls("reg" & x).value is showing blank. But I don't know how to fix it. I thought it's due to not selected even the value is assigned. But even after I add .selected(m-1)=true, it's still not reading the value to the listbox.

Comment: I don't think that's the right way to populate the control.  You should loop through all of the controls and cast the control to the proper type AND THEN set the value.   That's the way I've done it at least.

Comment: That's what I did:  I selected the item in the list and then assign the value:     frmSurvey.Controls("reg" & x).ListIndex = m - 1 frmSurvey.Controls("reg" & x).Selected(m - 1) = True frmSurvey.Controls("reg" & x).Value = answer. Can you provide some sample codes that worked? I may be able to see what my problem is.

Comment: As per the problem description, sub form is a child form of main form. Is it correct? Can you please show us the code how you have created the instance of subform in main form and the code when it is opened. What changes are you doing when sub form is closed ? OR subform is not closed when you change the list item selection in main form.